# How to loop over multiple subsets, perform operations and take the results to the original dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a dataframe with millions of rows, and about 100k unique ID numbers. I want to perform operations per unique ID. For now I generate a subset per unique ID and perform some operations accordingly. This loops works. But how do I efficiently combine the subsets into one dataframe?

Maybe there is a more efficient way to perform operations per subset of unique IDs.

Thanks

```
for ID in np.unique(df_fin['ID']):
    ID_subset = df_fin.loc[df_fin['ID'] == ID]

    for i in ID_subset.index:
        if ID_subset['date_diff'][i] > 0:
            for p in range(0,ID_subset['date_diff'][i]):
                if p == WIP:
                    sl.appendleft(ID_subset.return_bin[i-1])
                else:
                    sl.appendleft(0)

                lissa = list(sl)
                ID_subset.at[i,'list_stock'] = lissa

    frames = [ID_subset] #this does not work
    final_mod = pd.concat(frames) #this also does not work
```

THIS IS WORKING:
I also tried with groupby.apply. See the code below.

```
def create_stocklist(x):
    x['date_diff'] = x['dates'] - x['dates'].shift()
    x['date_diff'] = x['date_diff'].fillna(0)
    x['date_diff'] = (x['date_diff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
    x['list_stock'] = x['list_stock'].astype(object)
    x['stock_new'] = x['stock_new'].astype(object)

    var_stock = DOS*[0]
    sl = deque([0],maxlen=DOS)

    for i in x.index:
        if x['date_diff'][i] > 0:
            for p in range(0,x['date_diff'][i]):
                if p == WIP:
                    sl.appendleft(x.return_bin[i-1])
                else:
                    sl.appendleft(0)

                lissa = list(sl)
                x.at[i,'list_stock'] = lissa
    return x

df_fin.groupby(by=['ID']).apply(create_stocklist)
```

Comment: did you have the chance of taking a look to Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach could be:

```
for g, _id in df_din.groupby(by=['ID']):
    # do stuff with g
```

`g` is a dataframe containing all rows such that `df_fin['ID'] == _id`

Comment: Have done it with groupby.apply function. Thanks @Pierluigi